# Introductory MNIST example from Tensorflow results in Exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, error-handling

Running the first example on Tensorflow's tutorial results in an exception. Tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners

Code: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py

The error I am encountering is:

> An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback

I am using Python 3.6 and the latest version of Tensorflow. Can anyone else try running the code and see if a similar error occurs?

Comment: How do you run the script?

Comment: @Maxim I have tried running the script in Jupyter notebook (latest version) and Spyder. Both returned the same error.

Comment: Tensorflow forces process termination, that's the reason why it doesn't work in Jupyter - https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/issues/415

Comment: @Maxim Is there a way to modify this behavior? I can't seem to find the lines where it is calling for a process termination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is produced in ipython (Jupyter), because Tensorflow [forces system exit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py#L48), which ipython doesn't like. See for instance [this discussion](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/issues/415).

Luckily, system exit is done by `tf.app.run` method, so the solution for you is to inline the `FLAGS.data_dir` flag (set the local path to MNIST) and run `main` manually:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(None)
```

You can even go on and inline the whole `main` method if you like.